# Migrating FacebookAPI / restfb 1.6 to 1.36 results in deprecation warning and compile error

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm dealing with a legacy Java project that currently uses **restfb with the outdated version 1.6.11**. When updating the version to **1.36.0** some warnings popped up due to deprecated methods. Most of them complained about missing a `com.restfb.Version`, which I provided and everything is fine. But I'm a little stuck with the deprecation of `com.restfb.types.User`'s  `getUsername()`. Consulting the JavaDoc is not helpful as it does not give a hint what to use instead.

```
/**
 * The user's Facebook username.
 *
 * @return The user's Facebook username.
 * @since 1.6.5
 * @deprecated since graph api 2.0
 */
@Deprecated
@Getter
@Setter
@Facebook
private String username;
```

What other method / other way is suitable to get that piece of information as it is needed further on in the code?

Somewhere else in the code I also found a compile error concerning `com.restfb.types.Page`. `getPicture()` once returned a String as `the picture` which changed to `com.restfb.types.ProfilePictureSource`. Is `ProfilePictureSource`'s url the same data as "the picture" or has this data to be processed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer can be found in the [RestFB Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/restfb/jNJN4i-wQOU/l4DWrxM9AQAJ).

Short answer is:

1. `username` was removed by Facebook with Graph API 2.0 so it is deprecated without an hint. There is not alternative.
2. yes, the `ProfilePictureSource` url field is the former Page's `picture` field